# how to run a command in python, supplying input, then reading the output

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

I want to use Popen from subprocess 
to execute the command: 'python3 test.py'

```
# The following is test.py code:

string = input('Enter Something')
if string == 'mypassword':
    print('Success')
else:
    print('Fail')
```

In my program, I want to execute 'python3 test.py' multiple times, each time supplying input, and reading the output ('Success' or 'Fail') and storing it in a variable.

My program that is suppose to execute 'python3 test.py' is as follows:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

# Runs test.py
command = Popen(['python3', 'test.py'], stdin=PIPE)
# After this, it prompts me to type in the input, 
# but I want to supply it from a variable

# I want to do something like
my_input = 'testpassword'
command.supplyInput(my_input)
result = command.getOutput()

# result will have the string value of 'Success' or 'Fail'
```

Comment: os.system(command) is used to execute the commands

Comment: I would normally use that command if I am not going to be prompted an input, but I have to follow it with an input

Comment: You can pass input as command line arguments along with the command

Comment: I understand, but in this case there aren't command line arguments. The command must be ran first, then it prompts you to manually enter something

Comment: Just to be clear, the test.py file is not going to change. I want to modify the python program that will execute test.py correctly supplying it the input and getting the output

Answer (score 1):

You can add parameter `stdout=PIPE` to `Popen`, and use `Popen.communicate` to supply input and read the output instead.

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
command = Popen(['python3', 'test.py'], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE)
my_input = 'testpassword\n'
result, _ = command.communicate(my_input)
```

Please read `Popen.communicate`'s documentation for more details:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate